# List the elements of the group of rotational symmetries of the cube.

Tags: group-theory, rotations, symmetry

I'm looking for a list of the elements of the group of rotational symmetries of the cube.

I figured out that there are 24 rotational symmetries. Rotation fixing: faces = 9, diagonals = 8, edges = 6, identity = 1; total = 24.

Is this group abelian? 
I'm guessing that commutativity would be easily proven/disproven if I knew the list of the elements.

Any help would be great!

Comment: This group is $S_4$ and it's not abelian. Have you figured out what each symmetry does? If yes, then just label them and you have your list.

Comment: To see that it is $S_4$ directly, look at the action of your rotations on the $4$ pairs of opposite vertices.  (i.e. think of the four pairs as the four objects being permuted).

Comment: Try wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry#The_isometries_of_the_cube